# Small shift on HTML replace with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a server-side created HTML structure, which needs to be recreated and exchanged by jQuery (please don't ask why..).

But the strange thing is, when it gets replaced, also I has the exact same HTML structure, there is a tiny shift of some elements to the left.

I don't have any idea why this happens. Especially after extracted it and could recreate it in a fiddle..

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umoLc000/4/)

Do you see any potential solution?

I don't think it will be helpful if I post all the code here in the question. Therefore I just post the CSS. But if you want to see it, please let me know.

```css
.article_overview {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    width: 465px;
}

.article_overview .summaryRow {
    padding: 15px 10px 0;
    color: #838383;
}
.article_overview .articleRow {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #d9d9d9;
}
.article_overview .counter {
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
.article_overview .articleRow img {
    max-width: 60px;
}

.article_overview .image {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.article_overview .text {
    width: 84%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 60px;
}
.article_overview .information {
    width: 60%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.article_overview .articleAmount,
.article_overview .priceTotal {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.article_overview .articleAmount {
    width: 18%;
    text-align: center;
}
.article_overview .priceTotal {
    width: 19%;
    text-align: right;
}
.article_overview .articleNr {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about the little change when we press "press me" on your fiddle ?

Comment: yes! that's what I'm talking about!

Comment: If you "Inspect elements", you can see it doesn't have the same html structure. First you have `span`s and then you end up with `div`s

Comment: @David I compared the whole code line by line and couldn't find any difference. There was one different surrounding div in my first fiddle, but this wasn't the source of the problem. I updated my fiddle..

Comment: Ok, the problem is neither the markup nor the CSS style. I am working on it but I must admit it is very strange.

Comment: @David I found the solution, see my answer.. thank you nevertheless!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this

```
<span>Lorem ipsum</span>
<span>Lorem ipsum</span>
```

is not equal to this

```
<span>Lorem ipsum</span><span>Lorem ipsum</span>
```

The browser will add space between `span`s if you break the line.

With jQuery, you `append`ed it, so it didn't break the line between `span`s.

Haha !

---

To solve your problem, in your initial HTML code (Html, not jQuery), remove spaces between inline elements such as `span`

Comment: yes, you are correct. I didn't see your answer when I posted my "bugfix". :) I tried your approach and it also works! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the structure. You add an empty `<div>` just before `.summaryRow` div. I think this is produced by this line:

```
   var sAllProducts = jQuery('<div>');
```

To avoid this, try to `unwrap()` all the content after append it. See more:

https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this didn't fix unfortunately. I got rid of the extra div and the problem still exists. See my updated fiddle.